# MassTransit Saga Persistence with Azure CosmosDB doesn't work with containers with specified partition key

Tags: persistence, azure-cosmosdb, masstransit, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, saga

Azure Cosmos DB containers must have a partition key and the Azure portal doesn't allow creation of containers without partition key. The emulator also doesn't allow it. Containers without partitioned key are deprecated and only way to create those is via Powershell, CLI or old SDK. Behind the scene, the Cosmos DB is setting the partition key as "_partitionKey". Any containers created using Portal or CLI with partition key specified exactly as "_partitionKey" fails to work with MassTransit with error message as

```
PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
System.InvalidOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<AddPartitionKeyInformationAsync>d__344.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ReadDocumentPrivateAsync>d__233.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetryAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetryAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.DocumentDbIntegration.Saga.DocumentDbSagaRepository`1.<Send>d__16`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext<TMessage>>-Send>d__5.MoveNext()
```

This can be reproduced in one of MassTransit tests as well. The test would pass if we allow the tests to create the DB and container but it fails if we pre-create the DB and container (with the partition key set as "_partitionKey"). I have compared the Settings for the auto created container and manually created container and from what we have access to, there isn't any difference (See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc5si.png))

```
Test Name:  Should_have_removed_the_state_machine
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
Result StandardOutput:  
17:34:14.063-A Start MassTransit.Transport.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0. 
17:34:14.150-A Start MassTransit.Transport.Receive |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.
17:34:14.150-D SEND loopback://localhost/input_queue 7a000000-9a3c-0005-c0b7-08d7eb0be083 MassTransit.DocumentDbIntegration.Tests.GirlfriendYelling
17:34:14.153-A Stop  MassTransit.Transport.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0. -- 92ms
17:34:14.268-A Start MassTransit.Saga.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.1. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.
17:34:14.287-A Stop  MassTransit.Saga.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.1. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1. 18ms
17:34:14.292-W R-RETRY loopback://localhost/input_queue 7a000000-9a3c-0005-c0b7-08d7eb0be083

System.InvalidOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<AddPartitionKeyInformationAsync>d__344.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ReadDocumentPrivateAsync>d__233.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetryAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetryAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MassTransit.DocumentDbIntegration.Saga.Context.DocumentDbDatabaseContext`1.<Load>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\Code\Samples\MassTransit-develop\src\Persistence\MassTransit.DocumentDbIntegration\Saga\Context\DocumentDbDatabaseContext.cs:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MassTransit.DocumentDbIntegration.Saga.Context.DocumentDbSagaRepositoryContext`2.<Load>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Code\Samples\MassTransit-develop\src\Persistence\MassTransit.DocumentDbIntegration\Saga\Context\DocumentDbSagaRepositoryContext.cs:line 63
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MassTransit.Saga.SendSagaPipe`2.<Send>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Code\Samples\MassTransit-develop\src\MassTransit\Saga\SendSagaPipe.cs:line 36
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext<TMessage>>-Send>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Code\Samples\MassTransit-develop\src\MassTransit\Saga\Pipeline\Filters\CorrelatedSagaFilter.cs:line 52
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext<TMessage>>-Send>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Code\Samples\MassTransit-develop\src\MassTransit\Saga\Pipeline\Filters\CorrelatedSagaFilter.cs:line 70
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.RetryFilter`1.<GreenPipes-IFilter<TContext>-Send>d__4.MoveNext()
17:34:14.330-A Start MassTransit.Saga.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.2. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.
17:34:14.331-A Stop  MassTransit.Saga.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.2. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1. 927700ns
17:34:14.332-A Start MassTransit.Saga.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.3. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.
17:34:14.333-A Stop  MassTransit.Saga.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.3. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1. 739200ns
17:34:14.333-A Start MassTransit.Saga.Send |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.4. |e54a1ba8-452425b175a04fe0.1.
```

Is there a way to configure the MassTransit Saga Persistence to be able to work with containers created with partition key? The Azure Portal already doesn't allow containers without a partition key and eventually the CLI would also not allow (the commands are already deprecated).

[image: Container Settings]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you trying to find a way to work with collections without a user-defined partition key? Or is it something else?

Comment: @DavidMakogon updated. I want to find out if there is a configuration that I did not see in MassTransit that already takes care of this. Not everything in MassTransit is documented and so I was hoping that one of the maintainer can comment. I could not find a way around by looking at the code. Without that adressed, the use of CosmosDB as Saga storage would be difficult as when the CLI/SDK removes the legacy support, we won't be able to create new containers that MassTransit is able to work with.

Comment: If you didn't see it in the code, I doubt it supports PartitionKey containers. I've tested it with Cosmos from a Mac, and it works, that was 2-3 months ago. But I didn't write it, and don't know squat about it.